automatically calculate uncertainty propagation: regressi alternative?
I recently completed a lab on optics. I measured an angle of incidence i1 and a refraction angle i2. I recorded this data in a spreadsheet and plotted sin⁡i2=fn(sin⁡i1). I have an uncertainty of 1∘.
In the lab instructions, we were required to use Regressi, a somewhat outdated software with an unintuitive interface (but very powerful software)
 
Two columns for angles, two for uncertainties, two for the calculated sine values, and… wait for it: two automatically generated columns for the uncertainties in sine values! This is great, and as far as I know, there is no other free software with a GUI that offers this feature. After just a few clicks, I can define the regression expression (here it’s a simple y=a⋅x, but it can be more complex), and that’s it!
In Python, the equivalent setup would look like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# python -m venv venv
# source venv/bin/activate
# pip install uncertainties numpy matplotlib scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import uncertainties.unumpy as unp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Initial data (angles of incidence and refraction)
i1 = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
i2 = np.array([0, 6.5, 13, 19.5, 25.5, 31, 35.5, 39, 41.5])
σ = 1

# Convert to objects with uncertainties
sin_i1 = unp.sin(unp.radians(unp.uarray(i1, σ)))
sin_i2 = unp.sin(unp.radians(unp.uarray(i2, σ)))

# i₁ in degrees
# i₂ in degrees
# Uncertainty in degrees
# Calculate sin(i₁) with uncertainties
# Calculate sin(i₂) with uncertainties

# Extract nominal values and uncertainties
sin_i1_vals = unp.nominal_values(sin_i1)
# Central values of sin(i₁)
sin_i2_vals = unp.nominal_values(sin_i2)
# Central values of sin(i₂)
sin_i1_err = unp.std_devs(sin_i1)
# Uncertainties of sin(i₁)
sin_i2_err = unp.std_devs(sin_i2)
# Uncertainties of sin(i₂)

# Plot data with error bars
plt.errorbar(sin_i1_vals, sin_i2_vals, xerr=sin_i1_err, yerr=sin_i2_err, fmt=' g', label='Measurements')

# Linear regression model: f(x) = a*x (intercept b = 0)
def linear_model(x, a):
    return a * x

# Regression with curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(linear_model, sin_i1_vals, sin_i2_vals) # pcov: parameter covariance, not used but noted...
a_opt = popt[0] # Regression coefficient

# Plot the regression
plt.plot(sin_i1_vals, linear_model(sin_i1_vals, a_opt), 'tab:blue', label=f"Regression: sin i₂ = {a_opt:.4f} * sin i₁")

# Formatting and display
plt.title('sin i₂ = f(sin i₁)')
plt.xlabel('sin i₁')
plt.ylabel('sin i₂')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 0.7])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 0.8, 0.1))
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

(by the way, if you have suggestions on how I could improve this Python script, I’m open to ideas!)

It’s probably also possible in R (which I know even less than Python) or Octave.
But something has been on my mind for days. Regressi seems primarily used in France, so what software do students in other countries use to automatically calculate uncertainty propagation for their lab work? What do researchers use? (I assume they use Origin Pro since they don’t mind if it’s not free.)
So, I’ve been looking for an alternative.
First, I tried SciDaVis/Alphaplot, which I like a lot… but I couldn’t find how to propagate uncertainties automatically. I can, of course, create a column for σsin⁡θ=∣cos⁡(θ)∣×σθ manually, but to find this formula requires work, and now that I know a software does it automatically, I don’t want to do it myself anymore!
Then I tried labplot2, Gnuplot, LibreOffice Calc, GeoGebra, Dataplot, JASP, Jamovi. In none of these software options could I find this feature ???
I can’t believe Regressi is the only free software in the world that offers automatic uncertainty propagation. And if that’s the case, why??? What do non-French students use? Why hasn’t Regressi become more widely known and considered essential?
I must be missing something, can you please help me?

I don't think you're missing anything: error propagation is complex, and it's not unusual that the big, generic, open-source numeric libraries like Scipy haven't really covered it. For sin specifically, you could do it yourself; read PDF of function of X.

I remember I wrote some error propagation function for one of the graphs I wanted to include in a manuscript. Let me see if I can find it again :D

Managed to find the script, however I encountered a small problem, as the one I wrote takes into consideration a*x + b and the error mainly comes from propagating the rows of the gradient J.
I also exaggerated the error a bit by adding random noise (centered at 0).
The functions and imports are here:
%matplotlib qt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numdifftools as nd
import uncertainties.unumpy as unp
def LinearRegressionModel(x, a, b):
    ''' Simple linear regression as a*x + b '''
    return a * x  + b # Define the linear regression model
def proxy(r, x):
    ''' Proxy function for LinearRegressionModel '''
    return LinearRegressionModel(x, *r)  # Apply the model to x with parameters r
def propagation(J, Cp):
    ''' Define the propagation function to compute the covariance '''
    return J @ Cp @ J.T  # Covariance propagation
def error(x, p, Cp):
    ''' Define the error function '''
    gradient = nd.Gradient(lambda r: proxy(r, x))  # gradient function of proxy w.r.t. parameters
    J = gradient(p)  # get gradient at model parameters p
    Cy = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: propagation(row, Cp), 1, J) # propagate each row of the gradient
    sy = np.sqrt(Cy) # Calculate standard errors
    return sy

And this is the example:
i1 = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
i2 = np.array([0, 6.5, 13, 19.5, 25.5, 31, 35.5, 39, 41.5])
σ = 1
sin_i1 = unp.sin(unp.radians(unp.uarray(i1, σ)))
sin_i2 = unp.sin(unp.radians(unp.uarray(i2, σ)))
sin_i2 += np.random.normal(0, 0.05, len(sin_i2)) # inject some noise to exagerate, when removed it's not possible to see the results...
sin_i1_vals = unp.nominal_values(sin_i1)
sin_i2_vals = unp.nominal_values(sin_i2)
sin_i1_err = unp.std_devs(sin_i1)
sin_i2_err = unp.std_devs(sin_i2)
plt.errorbar(sin_i1_vals, sin_i2_vals, xerr=sin_i1_err, yerr=sin_i2_err, fmt=' g', label='Measurements')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(LinearRegressionModel, sin_i1_vals, sin_i2_vals)
sy = error(sin_i1_vals, popt, pcov)
predictions = LinearRegressionModel(sin_i1_vals, *popt)
plt.plot(sin_i1_vals, predictions)
plt.fill_between(sin_i1_vals, # x
                 predictions+sy, # upper = y + error
                 predictions-sy, # lower = y - error
                 alpha = 0.1, # make transparent
                )
plt.title('sin i₂ = f(sin i₁)')
plt.xlabel('sin i₁')
plt.ylabel('sin i₂')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 0.7])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 0.8, 0.1))

I injected some noise to the y variable to exagerate the error a bit, otherwise it was not really visible.

You can use the sy as you are using sin_i1_err or sin_i2_err.
This is a nice source to consider.
